# mod_rewrite not working with directory names

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I am using mod_rewrite to pass identifiers to my web app in the form:

```
http://clipi.ca/1W
```

I am identifying these with a simple regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?urlid=%1 [L,QSA]
```

...which works fine in most cases. However I noticed that when the identifier is the name of a directory, the rewrite is failing and Apache is returning a directory index!

How can I stop this behavior and have the rewrite rule apply to directories as well? (Note that as soon as an actual file inside a directory is referenced, the rewrite condition fails and it is not a problem.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have figured it out myself: Apparently, Apache will append a trailing slash to requests that map to directories on the filesystem *before* it applies any rewrite rules. That's kind of silly, imo, but by adding an optional trailing slash to my conditional regex:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/?$
```

...it seems to be working!

Still, the ideal solution would be to get Apache to *not* append that trailing slash to begin with. If anyone knows how to do that, post it here and I'll give you the answer credit.